# Regex - Split a string by commas (except commas in quotations) AND newlines (\n or \r)

Tags: java, regex

I'm currently using this regex found on another post:

```
",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)"
```

It's working wonderfully for me as I try to split a text file. I need to populate an array with each individual element in the text file, separated by commas (exclude commas inside quotes) and newline characters of any kind (this is a .txt file).

The above regex works for commas, how do I modify it to work for newline characters?

EDIT: Sorry, here are some examples of what I want to split:

```
20120102,1,1374,2,"Santorum, Rick","Romney, Mitt"
20120102,1,1158,2,99,"Romney, Mitt"
20120102,1,1237,26,99,99
20120102,1,1839,3,99,"Pennington, Matthew"
20120102,1,1431,25,99,99
20120102,1,976,5,99,99
20120104,1,1508,2,99,99
20120104,1,1379,2,99,99
```

So everything separated by commas would be an individual element. Each name (enclosed in quotes) are an individual element (BUT QUOTES WOULD NOT BE INCLUDED). \n, \r, and other newline characters would not be included. All these elements would be appended to an arraylist. I don't know if it's possible with regex.

Comment: Use `"[\r\n]+|,(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)"` or if the LF/CR inside quotes are not to be taken into account, `"[,\r\n]+(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)"`, or `"(?:,|[\r\n]+)(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)"`, or `"(?:,|\R)(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)"`... Try yourself, and when you have a problem, ask.

Comment: It didn't work for me... Are there any other characters for newlines that we need to add in there? This is a .txt file and the string is clearly represented on another line under the first.

Comment: Sorry, if you provided exact input string (as a string literal) and expected output it would be much easier. You would have already got an answer, I believe.

Comment: Do you want newlines to be split on except when they're inside quotes? Or split on newlines *or* commas not in quotes? Are you processing your file as one single big string (which I assume, since you seem to have newlines in your input, which wouldn't be there otherwise)? Please edit your question to provide example input and desired output.

Comment: Sorry about that everyone, updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

Something like `String[] arr="foo\nbar,\"fo,o\"\n\"bar\"".split("(\\r|\\n|,)(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)")`

To add to ArrayList with `for(String e:arr){arraylist.add(e.replaceAll("^\"|\"$", ""));}`

--

But I suspect this Regex is broken for some corner cases. Using a library should be better than Regex. E.g. http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/

Comment: This didn't seem to work. I added an update to the post.